# Accessing nested packages from top level with importlib (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-import

I have a project hierarchy like the following simplified example:

```
├── pacOne
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── pacTwo
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── modTwo.py
└── main.py
```

There's many more packages at the `pacTwo` level in my example, which I load according to a YAML file with the following function at `main.py`. It's a function because in the actual program, there's a little bit more that it does, which I've excluded for the relevence of this post.

```
def loadModules(modules):
    for module in modules:
        moduleImport = importlib.import_module("pacOne." + module)
        globals()["pacOne." + module] = moduleImport
```

After importing the module, I cannot figure out how to access `modTwo`. It imports just fine, no errors, but once trying to access it I get errors saying `modTwo` is not an attribute of pacTwo.

Here's an example of how I'm attempting to access `modTwo`:

```
globals()["pacOne." + module].modTwo.testFunc()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pacOne.pacTwo' has no attribute 'modTwo'
```

So the question is how can I access `modTwo.py` from `main.py` with `importlib` like above? Or is it simply impossible, because I just shouldn't be doing this?

---

**Edit:**

Changing the import function to be like:

```
def loadModules(modules):
    for module in modules:
        moduleImport = importlib.import_module("pacOne." + module + ".modTwo")
        globals()["pacOne." + module + ".modTwo"] = moduleImport
```

and accessing it like:

```
globals()["pacOne." + module + ".modTwo"].testFunc()
```

results in:

```
AttributeError: module 'pacOne.pacTwo.modTwo' has no attribute 'testFunc'
```

Which is weird, because when I inspect it with `inspect` like:

```
print(inspect.getmembers(moduleImport, inspect.isfunction))
```

I find:

```
[('testFunc', <function testFunc at 0x7f5878df4d08>)]
```

I'm not really sure what to make out of that. I can only assume I need to call it differently, but I have no idea how.

Comment: You need to import `modTwo` itself, not just `pacTwo`.  Modules inside a package aren't automatically imported just because you import the package.

Comment: @BrenBarn `globals()["pacOne." + module + ".modTwo"].testFunc()` does not work either when imported as `"pacOne." + module + ".modTwo"`. Same error basically: `AttributeError: module 'pacOne.pacTwo.modTwo' has no attribute 'testFunc'`

Comment: @BrenBarn I added new information I discovered from changing it to your recommendation.